# unable to access jarfile alliance.tmp

Tags: java, p2p, jar, jvm

I've just installed the p2p software Alliance. Whenever I'm trying to open Alliance a "Java Virtual Machine Launcher" window pops up with this error message: "unable to access jarfile alliance.tmp".
What can I do to use Alliance anyway?

Some technical details:
I'm talking about Alliance 1.0.6 http://www.alliancep2p.com/index.shtml. I'm using Windows 7 professional.

Comment: have you tried reinstalling it with a newly downloaded setupfile?

Comment: Yes. I tried. Still doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have WIndows 7 also.  Browse to C:\Program Files\Alliance.  Right click on Alliance.exe and select 'Run as administrator'.  You'll notice that a file alliance.tmp is now created in the C:\Program Files\Alliance directory and the program will actually load and run like the screenshots on their website.